# MongoException: Index with name: code already exists with different options

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-indexes

I have a `mongodb` collection `term` with following structure

```
{
    "_id" : "00002c34-a4ca-42ee-b242-e9bab8e3a01f",
    "terminologyClass" : "USER",
    "code" : "X67",
    "terminology" : "some term related notes",
    "notes" : "some notes"
}
```

and a java class representing the term collection as `Term.java`

```
@Document
public class Term{  

    @Id
    protected String termId;

    @Indexed
    protected String terminologyClass;

    @Indexed(unique=true)
    protected String code;

    @Indexed
    protected String terminology;

    protected String notes;

    //getters & setters
}
```

I have many documents in `term` collection. Now I am added a new field to `Term.java` as

```
@Indexed
protected String status;
```

After adding field `status` to `Term.java`, while inserting a new term to `term` collection I am getting an the exceptoin :

> com.mongodb.MongoException: Index with name: code already exists with
>   different options

I am using MongoDB version : 2.6.5 and spring-data-mongodb version : 1.3.2

Comment: Not exactly related to this issue, but it's the same error message, so might be useful for people searching: You can't add two TEXT indexes to a collection with different parameters. There can only be one (though it can reference multiple fields). See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You already have an index on that collection with the same name, but with a different definition. My guess is that your current code index is non-unique

try:
`db.Term.getIndexes()`

If this is indeed the case (you have a non-unique index over code field), issue:
`db.Term.dropIndex("code_1")`
(replace with the code field index name).

Next time you boot your application, it's supposed to work alright.

Alternatively, remove the unique attribute from the `@Indexed` annotation (if you don't except it to be unique).

Comment: Your guess is correct. Dropped the index on code and removed duplicates from code and then rebooting the application fixed the issue.  Thank You :)

Comment: I downgraded the version of my Ruby MongoDB library, and suddenly all my indexes with "expireAfterSeconds" already existed with different options, so I had to drop them all.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried to drop your collection and try again? usually there are many conflicts while applying new java mapping to existing mongodb collection

Comment: This worked, but make sure you don't need the data inside the collection or copy it somewhere then restore it!

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to create multiple compound **text** indexes can also cause this error.

Only one **text** index for text search is allowed per collection [per the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/).

In a multitenant database, we wanted to enforce uniqueness within each customer's data by using compound indexes.

```
db.users.createIndex( { customer: "text", email: "text"}, { unique: true } );
db.users.createIndex( { customer: "text", cell: "text"}, { unique: true } );
```

Doing this caused the op's error.

However, changing them to regular indices resolved the issue.

```
db.users.createIndex( { customer: 1, email: 1}, { unique: true } );
db.users.createIndex( { customer: 1, cell: 1}, { unique: true } );
```