# How to check whether a certain field is indexed in mongodb or not?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I know `db.collection.getIndexes()` can return all the indexes in `collection`, but sometimes it will return a long result if `collection` has many indexes, and this will make it difficult for you to find whether a certain field is indexed.

So how can you check whether **a certain field** is indexed in mongodb?

Comment: This should help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019313/checking-if-an-index-exists-in-mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can easily view whether you field is indexed or not using below query:

```
 db.collection.stats().indexSizes().c2_YOUR_FIELD_NAME
```

In above query, use your own collection name and field name. If it returns some value on console, the field is indexed.

[THIS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/indexes/#how-do-i-determine-which-fields-to-index) will give you much indepth-knowhow